# Can we get some more system help checking on new users?

Tags: feature-request

There are some new users that just scroll through the tour and get the 'informed' badge, and then start using the site in, what I think, is the wrong way:

- post a poorly asked question; it gets put on hold/closed as unclear what you asking; they repost the same or a slightly reworded question
- post a concise question which however is only a small part of the things the OP cannot fix; it gets one or more answers; the OP decides that doesn't completely solve their problem, so they extend the question, invalidating the answers.¹

Apart from the first post these questions don't show up in the `First Posts` review queue, and not necessarily "Low Quality" posts, so it usually depends on someone remembering that the same OP posted similar or related questions on an earlier date.

Based on any of the following:²

- low average reputation per question asked so far
- downvotes on X percent of questions asked
- on hold/closed questions in the last Y days that the OP did not try to get reopened
- low participation (acceptance of answers, votes cast)

Can new questions by OPs fulfilling these criteria, either be be put in the First Posts queue, or put in some new queue that and be shown in some more context (links to the other, closed, questions). The OP should be notified that (s)he is in extended review mode and why that is the case.

And additionally can these users maybe be prompted to take a small quiz that shows they understand the operations of the site and as long as they fail the test are not allowed to post new questions?

I am all for initial faith in people doing the right thing, but I think a system response against initial misuse, recognised based on published criteria, works better than some user notifying and complaining in comments to the OP.

¹ <sub>And in the process might just ignore formatting and spelling improvements on their original post (https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/165652/revisions rev 2-3)</sub>
² <sub>There might be more, also relevant, criteria</sub>

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158148/should-there-be-an-optional-community-guideline-quiz-in-the-faq-that-can-earn-a, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164346/should-there-be-a-test-for-new-users

Comment: @MichaelMrozek thanks for the pointers, I always forget there is meta meta as well (that is how I see meta.stackexchange.com not sure if that is correct). Unfortunately the Analytical badge (mentioned in the only and accepted answer to the first post) is retired.

Comment: I [answered that second post about a quiz](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242991/186664), partly repeating what I wrote here.

Comment: **Quiz question 1:**
What are the allowed topics on the site? 
**a) unix b) Linux c) who cares I will post my question anyways by creating a new account!**

Comment: @Ramesh That is a possibility, but a new account's post will at least show up in the First Posts queue once.

Comment: To post on this site, you must download the ATT ksh source package.